# Approximation of a measurable function by a continuous one

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable. Prove for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $g\in C([0,1])$ st.
$$|\{x: f(x) \neq g(x)\}| < \epsilon$$

This seems to be a standard result, but I couldn't find a proof. Maybe someone can give a reference? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 2.23, referred to there as Lusin's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Real Analysis by Royden, has, I believe, a proof.

Comment: You should provide a name for the result and/or page it can be found on.